# Unable to tell if Quantmod is retrieving Quarterly or Yearly Dividends - R

Tags: r, verification, quantmod, stock

I am working on getting stock dividends via [quantmod](/questions/tagged/quantmod) for various companies. The issue I am running into is the inability to tell whether I am retrieving the quarterly amount each company is paying out, or the annualized amount.

For example, let's say I am looking for the most recent dividend amounts for Cintas and BlackRock.

```
getDividends("CTAS")
getDividends("BLK")
```

The result of the above code for Cintas gives a dividend of $2.55, which is their annualized dividend (according to `Nasdaq`).

But when I do the same for BlackRock, the dividend shows as $3.63, which is their quarterly dividend. I would then need to multiply by 4 to get to their annualized dividend of $14.52 so I can then compare the 2 companies on the same scale.

**I have no issue with getting the dividends with [quantmod](/questions/tagged/quantmod) - just need to know/verify what exactly I am retrieving**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with quantmod, but with the data. There is no indicator in the data to show if the dividend is annual or quarterly (or monthly). CTAS has an annual dividend, BLK a quarterly. You would have to count the dividend occurence in the year before to see with what kind of dividend you are dealing with.

You could do something with `apply.yearly` to roll up the dividends to annual data. But this will not tell you what the forward dividend is going to be.

```
blk <- getDividends("BLK")
apply.yearly(blk, sum)
           BLK.div
2003-12-01    0.40
2004-12-01    1.00
2005-12-01    1.20
2006-11-30    1.68
2007-11-29    2.68
2008-12-01    3.12
2009-11-24    3.12
2010-12-01    4.00
2011-12-01    5.98
2012-11-29    6.00
2013-11-29    6.72
2014-12-01    9.65
2015-12-01    8.72
2016-12-08    9.16
2017-12-01   10.00
2018-12-06   12.02
2019-12-05   13.20
2020-03-04    3.63
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thought that multiplying a quarterly dividend to get annual may give false results because dividends change on the whim of the board.  This quarters dividend may disappear because of say CV19, or they've just invested in a huge new plant which will take a while to see returns, and may even have given a bigger dividend in the previous quarter letting shareholder know the forward plans.